# Is the function $f(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if}\ x\ \text{is rational} \\ x, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$, continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $$f(x)= \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x\ \text{is rational} \\
      x, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

My question is - Is the function continuous at zero? I understood that the function is not continuous at any other points in $\mathbb{R}$. But for zero I think it is continuous as for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ consisting of rational and irrationals that converges to zero, the function takes the value $0$ for rationals which obviously converges to $0$ and for irrationals the function is the identity function which also goes to $0$ as $x_n$ goes to zero. Am I correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but it would be more natural to prove the continuity at $0$ from the definition of continuity.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Depending on the educational level and textbook author, that _is_ the definition. But yeah, I'd prefer to see $\epsilon$-$\delta$ as well.

Comment: This is the canonical example of a function that is continuous at a single point. If you search "continuous at a single point" you will see this example mentioned everywhere.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I was narrow-minded here.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much all of you. I find the sequence definition a bit easier to visualize.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much for the reference. But this question is a little bit different from that. This function is taking the value 0 for rationals but the question that you have referenced, the function is taking the value 0 for irrationals.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference. You can prove it the same way.

Comment: Yes, of course, the proof is the same. I just checked.